# How to find the direction of maximum increase?

Tags: vectors

For a room of side length $k$ the vertices of which are

$(0,0,0),(k, 0, 0),
(0, k, 0), (0, 0,k), (k, k, 0), (k, 0, k), (0, k, k), (k, k, k)$

The temperature within this rooms is given by the scalr field $T(x,y,z) =T_{0}xyz$ where $T_{0}$ is a constant.

I have three question.

1. where is the hottest point in the room
2. In the centre of the room what is the direction of maximum increase of temperature?
3. Find the function $T_{x=0}(yz)$ and $T_{x=a}(yz)$

My working so far:

1. The hottest point is at (k,k,k)
2. $\nabla T= T_0yzi +T_0xzj+T_0xyk $

So the direction of maximum increase of temperature is in positive x,y,z direction?

3)
$T_{x=0}(yz) =0$

$T_{x=a}(yz)=T_0 ayz$

Comment: In 1), what is $a$?  In 2), what do you mean by "outwards"? In 3) the first expression is correct, but look at the second again.

Comment: I corrected my mistakes for 1 and 3. However i am struggling with 2

Answer (score 1):

You've got the gradient correct; it's $$yz\mathbf i +xz\mathbf j + xy \mathbf k$$  At the center of the cube, we have $x=y=z=\frac k2$, so you need to substitute these values in the formula for the gradient.  Actually, since $x=y=z$, we can see that the direction is $\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k$ without doing any substitution.

Sometimes, "direction" is taken to mean a unit vector.  If your instructor follows this convention, you'll have to normalize the vector.